# jquery - div inside script invalidates page

Tags: javascript, jquery, w3c-validation

I have the following js code:

```
$('<div id="pips-calc" />').load("/calculator").appendTo('body').dialog(dialogOpts); return false;}
```

W3C does not like this and invalidates the page.
The error is:

```
document type does not allow element "div" here
```

Is there any alternative syntax, which does validate?

Comment: It's validating dynamically generated HTML?

Comment: Do you have a form tag inside body?

Comment: Does it work around the problem by delimiting your inline JS code with CDATA markers as shown here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format the content of the `<script>` tag as CDATA, and you will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Either put the Javascript into a separate file or enclose it in `<![CDATA[ .... ]]>`

Answer (score -2):

Don't put it like this

```
$('<div id="pips-calc" />').
```

Instead do this

```
$('#pips-calc').
```